# How to speed up sql sub query

Tags: sql, query-optimization, sql-optimization

i'm running a job and its taking too long to run.

I have created a job to update based on the value of multiple tables

```
UPDATE applicant_scores 
  SET applicant_scores.Age=2.5
where applicant_scores.Applicant_id in 
  (select applicantinfo.subebno from applicantinfo
   WHERE SUBSTR(applicantinfo.DOB,7,4) ='1985')
```

This should update a column with about 17000 rows, but it's taking too long time.

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: I'd guess `SUBSTR(applicantinfo.DOB,7,4) ='1985'` is the problem. How is that column indexed?

Comment: Create a temp table containing the results from the subquery in the `WHERE IN` clause, and index it.

Comment: How do you know the subquery is the bit that takes the time?

Comment: Using SUBSTR in your subquery is probably what kills it. Looks like you're storing dates in a string format; consider converting the applicantinfo.DOB column to a date format (best practice) and use the Year function (with an index created on that column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
WHERE SUBSTR(applicantinfo.DOB,7,4) ='1985'
```

The database doesn't have a way to quickly find all the rows that match that criteria.  There's no index.  It has to check every row in the database to find the ones that match that expression.

One solution you have is you can add another column to your table, maybe call it `dob_year`, then is just the year out of that date.  Then, you `CREATE INDEX applicantinfo_dob_year ON applicantinfo(dob_year)`.   Then change your `WHERE` clause to `WHERE dob_year  ='1985')`

https://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a great site for learning about database indexes and how to use them properly to make your queries fast.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `not exists` and an index:

```
UPDATE applicant_scores 
  SET applicant_scores.Age = 2.5
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM applicantinfo ai
                WHERE appliacnt_scores.Applicant_id = ai.subebno AND 
                      SUBSTR(ai.DOB, 7, 4) ='1985'
               );
```

For performance, you want an index on `applicantinfo(subebno, DOB)`.

Note:  `DOB` probably means "date of birth".  It should be stored as a `date` in your database and you should be using proper date functions, such as:

```
extract(year from dob) = 1985
year(dob) = 1985
dob >= '1985-01-01' and dob < '1986-01-01'
```

Do not store dates as strings.  Do not use string functions on dates.

Answer (score 0):

````
   SET Age_Score=(SELECT Age_Score FROM age_scoretbl WHERE  SUBSTR(applicantinfo.DOB,7,4)= age_scoretbl.Birth_Year);```
````

Comment: I ignored table appliacnt_scores and populate applicantinfo.Age_Score From age_scoretbl.Birth_Year. This was fast . Thanks Gordon Linoff for the advise on date data type. Noted ! Thanks all.